# FedEx Shipping Rate Error in Multi-Store

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

My store running in India, for courier service we using FedEx, using Magento-Fedex Extension, if my Magento website base currency is INR the rate calculation looking fine, supposed if my base currency is Dollar the rate is not converted to the Dollar price, the price like $1,700(Actually 1,700 is INR)

Other Services working Good,

[image]